# Cakephp 3 installation on Ubuntu doesn't have permission to access index.php

Tags: ubuntu, 403-forbidden, permissions

I have installed Cakephp on my ubuntu webserver (well copied it in var/www/html) following this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/questions/628938/how-to-install-cakephp-in-ubuntu-14-04

I am also using this Version (14.04 LTS) and did everything. But now I am getting this

```
You don't have permission to access /webroot/index.php on this server.
```

Which is strange. I set the permissions on 755 for this folder and also for index.php in webroot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a no brainer, [folder ownership!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Try doing the following:

- `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /webroot`